# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've a services model in my ruby on rails project but I'm unable to render it in pages#home view of my project I'm getting this **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** Although I've defined the variable in my Servicecontroller-

My ServicesController file-

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @services = Service.all
  end
end
```

My show file-

```
<div class="container">

  <h3>Services we offer-</h3>
  <% @services.each do |service| %>
        <h5><%= service.name %></h5>
        <p><%= service.description %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the path of my show file of services view is this- `app\views\services\_show.html.erb` and I'm rendering it in my pages views `app\views\pages\home.html.erb` as `<%= render 'services/show' %>`, I'm still getting the error although I'm able to see all services in rails console using @services=Service.all command.

Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: If you want to set the instance variable `@services = Service.all`when the request is being processed by `PagesController#home` you need to actually set the instance variable in **that** method. Setting an instance variable in another controller does absolutely nothing. And `show` in rails shows a single record. `index` corresponds to a collection of records.

Comment: Thank you It worked, I moved @services=Service.all in my pagesconroller and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the variable in the wrong controller and action.

If you want the `@services` instance variable to be available in the `home.html.erb` view, you'll need to set that data in `PagesController#home`.

If you set the variable in the correct action and then render a partial inside the `home` view, beit `_show` or another one, you'll be able to access that variable.

Try something like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def home
    @services = Service.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I just have one more question, What if I don't want to name my show file as '_show.html.erb' instead I want it as 'show.html.erb' then how to render such it?

Comment: If that is a partial (part of a view that will be rendered inside another), it's a convention that you name it starting with `_`. In that case, calling it `show` may not be a good idea since that is the name that the `ServicesController#show` action will search for when trying to render its associated view.